# Gluon Mobile 2.2.0 : How to change ProgressBar/ProgressIndicator color?

Tags: javafx, gluon, gluon-mobile

Default color of the `com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.ProgressIndicator/ProgressBar` is material design ***blue***.

How to change the color?

I tried different JavaFX CSS properties, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the color by using a new css style `-fx-color`.

```
progressIndicator.setStyle("-fx-color: red;");
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, it works! Thank you. It seems that `-fx-color` is not custom JavaFX CSS property, isn't it? I haven't found that in Gluon documentation.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I think its somehow missed in the documentation.